# How can I combine two Arrays by parallel collections in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have two arrays Array1(1, 2, 3) and Array2(4, 5, 6).
I want to combine them to a new Array3((1,4),(2,5),(3,6))
While when I try that in Spark it becomes.

code

```
val data1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val data2 = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val distData1 = sc.parallelize(data1)
val distData2 = sc.parallelize(data2)

val distData3 = distData1 ++ distData2
distData3.foreach(println)
```

output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I combine them correctly?

//Update*

In my program(different from the example). I want to label.zip(features). My features are features: Array[String] and my label are also Array[String]. Why it won't work?

```
<console>:98: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
required: scala.collection.GenIterable[?]
```

Comment: Do you care about posting the exact code ? This code isn't correct. You can't do distData3.foreach(println) and get an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `data1.zip(data2)` but it won't work if distributions are different.